# Is our internal SSO design secure?

Tags: authentication, sso

We use one primary web app that was built internally and 3 other web apps that we did not build but that we do host. I want users to only have to sign into the primary web app, which uses Google auth. The three other web apps only offer username/password, but all 3 have an API. We have run a proof of concept of the following design and I'm interested if I've missed any big holes. The workflow:

1. User signs into the primary web app (APP A) using Google auth
2. The user clicks a button in APP A triggering SSO to one of the secondary apps (APP B)
3. APP A makes an ajax request to its API asking for a valid password for APP B
4. APP A's API calls APP B's API and resets the user's password to a new randomly generated, long, complex password **THAT IT DOES NOT STORE**
5. APP A's API returns the new password to the browser
6. The browser fills that password into the password field of a form that is a copy of the login form for APP B
7. The browser posts that form to the login url of APP B
8. You are now logged into APP B

* All requests are sent over HTTPS

The reasons we want to do this:

- User's don't have to remember or type 4 passwords
- Passwords will change frequently (on every login)
- There will never be any weak passwords

I'd love your thoughts on the process, and if there are any major security holes I'm missing.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't see your code, so I have no idea. Also, what happens if someone steals the cookie and session?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Google auth"? Do you mean Google Authenticator?

Comment: How does App A's API authenticate to the API for App B (or the other two subsidiary apps)?  If that mechanism is insufficiently robust it sounds like an attacker who could take advantage of that could just tell App B to reset its password to whatever the attacker liked. I would also take a very careful look at the sequence of events between the point where each new password is generated to the point where App B receives the password submission from the browser, for the potential of stuff like password leakage over insecure traffic or due to interactions with other code running in the browser.

Comment: Your specific implementation is different, but the answer is the same: since you have some form of control over B, use something like OpenID or SAML2. Even better, log into B via Google since that's already your authentication.

Comment: @MarkHulkalo while stealing cookie or session is possible that isn't introduced by my workflow correct? That was inherent in the original password based login of the apps.

Comment: @paj28 sign in with google

Comment: @halfinformed App A authenticates to App B using a short-lived token generated by App B. You're second point was the one I was most concerned about, though it doesn't it doesn't strike me as more dangerous than typing the password into the browser, am I correct in that regard?

Comment: @JeffFerland thanks, ideally I'd like to implement google sign-in directly in those apps, but I don't have that level of access to those apps.